# How to blur SimpleDraweeView in Android Studio with Fresco Library

Tags: blur, fresco

I try many ways but all fails. Some can help me. Thank you very much. 
I tried this, but fail too: https://github.com/s13524801/android-fresco-blur/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/blur/MainActivity.java

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/844 It't not working

Answer (score 6):

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(<your url>))
                    .setPostprocessor(new IterativeBoxBlurPostProcessor(7))
                    .build();
```

then

```
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                    .setImageRequest(request)
                    .setOldController(<your imageView>.getController())
                    .build();
            imageRest.setController(controller);
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? This is mostly code

Comment: I LOVEEEEEE YOUUUUUU

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple solution:

```
Postprocessor postprocessor = new BlurPostprocessor(this,50);
        ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(url))
                .setPostprocessor(postprocessor)
                .build();
        PipelineDraweeController controller = (PipelineDraweeController) Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
                .setOldController(background.getController())
                .build();
        background.setController(controller);
```